# Build Dao For Common database functions

Tags: jpa, implementation, dao

I am trying to code a BaseDao class for common Database functions like findAll, findById, insert, update, deleteById, etc.

I have taken an interface BaseDao.java and another class BaseDaoAdapter.java implements BaseDao.java.

This Dao is injected into service. So Service classes which require common CRUD functionality will use this Dao, and those that require specific functionality will have their own Dao.

We have done this to reduce code duplication across the Dao layer.

The code for the class, which I wrote is as follows.

```
@Repository
public class BaseDaoAdapter {
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @PersistenceUnit
    public void setEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param tableName Name of table from which data has to be retrieved
     * @return A list of all the records in the specified table
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<? extends BaseEntity> list(String tableName){
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Query q =em.createQuery("SELECT A FROM "+tableName+" A");
        return q.getResultList();
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param obj An object of the entity that is to be inserted into the database.
     */
    public void add(BaseEntity obj){
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(obj);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }



    /**
     * 
     * @param obj Entity object to be deleted from the database
     */
    public void remove(BaseEntity obj){
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(obj);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
    }

}
```

Here the BaseEntity is an interface which all domain classes implement.

The (? extends BaseEntity) syntax sometimes gives errors when I try to cast the list returned by query to any domain specific list for example List.

We have done this because we want to return only a domain specific list.

I would like to ask two questions here.

- 1) Whether the approach we are following is correct?
- 2) Is there any better way to implement this BaseDaoAdapter so that we do not get type casting issues?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read Google App Engine's documentation on the subject of Polymorphism very carefully.  Some JDO inheritance relationships may not yet be supported.  Additionally, it may also be a good idea to store a Key reference if you attempt this method.

[Google App Engine JDO Documentation on Polymorphism](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Polymorphic_Relationships)